# PLSQL Procedure to change data across a full database

Tags: plsql

I've been asked to write a PLSQL procedure to 'clean up' codes in a database. The codes are varchar2 and are something like 00000001. They are used everywhere in the application. My new employer wants me to make the codes more readable as in turn the 00000001 into just 1 for everywhere they are used.

My question is how would one even go about that? I asked for clarification and it's still not clear and for fear of looking foolish I won't ask again. Any guidance would be welcome

Comment: Hey! are you talking about look up / configuration values defined in tables - changing values "0000001" in tables to 1?

Comment: @ Sankar Krishnamoorthy, sorry took so long to reply i never got any notification of your comment. I believe I am talking about lookup values. The values reference pieces of hardware the system uses, they are used in joins and other procedures all over the the place

Comment: can you paste a sample code here?
occurences like 00000001 are in table's columns or it has been hard coded in package,procedure codes.?

Comment: The values 0000001 etc are in the table columns. They are used for joining tables to create views amongst other things. It is obviously hard to explain because it's quite hard for me to even understand what is required

Answer (score 0):

let me start by saying that that sounds like a VERY BAD IDEA!!!!

if you persist it sound like you will need to use dynamic sql with the basic process of...

- query all_tab_cols to get a list of columns( im hoping all your columns that use these codes have a naming standard.. ie xxx_CD )
- loop over tab/cols to see if your value is there
- update values  in that table
- ...
- profit ?

however then you get stuck by realities.. if the code is in a foreign key you cant just update it. you'd have to create a new parent record.. update all children to new parent then delete old parent.

you'd need to be very clear on what you are trying to achieve.. and more importantly, is there any value in it?

i suggest you start with a single codevalue to scope out the size of project.
manually start writing the `update`s you'd need for that 1 codevalue and then try to start automating it.